# knockout.js. Loading spinner appears only after the operation

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to understand KnockoutJS. I want a spinner during the execution of some code. But why the spinner appears only after the operation?

```
<img data-bind="visible: isLoading" src="loading.gif">

<a href="#" data-bind="click: someOperation">Click</a>

<script type="text/javascript" src="knockout-2.2.1.js"></script>
<script>
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.isLoading = ko.observable(false);
    self.someOperation = function() {
        self.isLoading(true); 
        for(i = 0; i < 30000; i++)
            console.log('lol');
        self.isLoading(false);      
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
</script>
```

Thanks,
Fedor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED: First answer was wrong!

In chrome the console is asynchronous and console.log() is not happening where expected.

Using setTimeout works fine. See this fiddle [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vnrab/)

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.isLoading = ko.observable(false);
    self.someOperation = function() {
        self.isLoading(true);
        window.setTimeout(function() { self.isLoading(false) }, 1000);
        //for(i = 0; i < 30000; i++)
       //     console.log('lol');
        ///self.isLoading(false);      
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: It's working with setTimeout. But it's not working not only with console.log(). It's also not working with any loops. See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xAs5K/

Comment: Your fiddle does work, the loop is extremely fast and console.log is happening asynchronously. i.e `self.isLoading(false)` is happening before `console.log('lol')`. Putting a breakpoint on the `for(i = 0; i < 30000; i++)` line will show your loading image.

Comment: look into promises if you want to wait until something asynchronous is finished before you do something else. [http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/](q.js is a good library)

Comment: Thanks. I've done it. Q.fcall(startLoopFunction).then(hideSpinnerFunction); works for me.